# Mongodb Update using C++ API

Tags: c++, mongodb

I have written a C++ function to update a mongodb document. It is as below.

```
void
LocationDb::setServingRouter(string sensor, string oAp, string nAp) {

    m_conn.update("location_db.ldb",
                  BSON("id" << sensor << "name" << "/temp/s/1" << "ap" << BSON("name" << oAp)),
                  BSON("id" << sensor << "name" << "/temp/s/1" << "ap" << BSON("name" << nAp)));
}
```

This update query is working; however, I believe it has some limitation i.e. every time I update, I need to pass it the old ap name (oAp).

I find this very annoying in the sense that I just want to update the ap name without bothering was old name is. As per this query implementation, it is first finds the matching record in the document, and then update it.

How can I just update by matching the query partially? Bottom line is that I don't want to remember what old record was. Any help?